# Evolutionary Simulation - Persistent Threads for Timer Event Handling

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, evolutionary-algorithm

I am working on a simple evolutionary algorithm.

### How it works:

I have a gird map, on which every cell is either Blank, a Plant or a Herbivore.
Plants and herbivores are Creatures (plants are not, whatever), so they both have energy and a color. Creatures do stuff every few milliseconds (when a timer fires). Plants constantly recharge energy, herbivores lose energy. If a plant fully recharges, it looks in a random direction(north, south, east or west) and if the neighbouring cell in that direction is blank, the plant reproduces into that cell. Herbivores regain energy by eating plants. When it's a herbivore's turn to do stuff, it looks at a random neighbouring cell. If it's empty, the herbivore moves there. If it's a plant, the herbivore tries to eat it and then move there. The closer the herbivore's color to the plant's', the more chance the herbivore succeeds. If a herbivore reaches 0 energy, it dies. If a herbivore reaches maximum energy, it also reproduces. Offsprings always have a slightly different color than their parents'.

Here's a picture:

[image]

This is a lot of plants being eaten from the inside.

After a while, the system normalizes:

[image]

The big patches disappear and several colors are present at any time. This is expected, of course.

So, i have a working program now. However, it is ran by a single thread, and i want to make it multi-threaded. I'm planning to go as far as make a thread for every cell on the map.

I know it is overkill, but i want to do it anyways. That way, i could have these little atomic pieces, the cells, and all of them would work asynchronously, and they could be plugged into eachother on the fly, as if putting together puzzle pieces.

So that's the basic idea. I want to make the cells as autonomous as possible. I have tried to implement this: I created a swing timer for every cell, and when the timer fired, i started a thread for the cell to operate in. I also added locks to every cell so that shtuff doesn't get messed up when multiple neighbours try to access the same cell. The problem with this is that a new thread is invoked each time a cell tries to do something. I know this is very resource consuming (first hand experience) so i want to somehow make persistent threads for every cell. Each thread would handle it's own cell's timer, action listener and run the actions of it's cell when the timer fires. These threads would basically never discontinue. I need help with this, since i'm not sure how to implement such a system.

EDIT: Clarifying the question: I need an example of a thread that listens to a timer event and runs stuff when the timer fires. This should all happen inside the thread.

Comment: You should have at most a few dozen threads (on a simple laptop or desktop). Don't think of many thousands of them. So have essentially a small pool of threads (independently of the number of cells).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch The idea is scalability. If i only make 4 cells, i have 4 threads. I don't care about the numbers. I just need to know how to achieve such functioning.

Comment: I think that increasing threads only makes sense if you increase cpu cores. You can take hyper threading into account. So for example if you have a quadcore cpu with HT enabled then it can handle 8 threads simultaenously.

Comment: @Adam: you are mostly right, but you might have a little more threads than HT processors (i.e. slightly more than the number of entries in your `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux, but not a lot more) since the kernel could schedule them.

Comment: @Adam Arold I want to localise behaviour control for every cell to better represent a "real life scenario", as real as it gets with something like this. I want every cell to operate on it's own asynchronously, in it's own little world, in it's thread. My main focus is not optimality, but i need persistent threads, hence the post. I don't care if i end up with more threads than cores.

Comment: I've just came up with an answer with some suggestions.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code in a single thread?  That may help with coming up with better suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that increasing the number of `Thread`s only makes sense if you increase cpu cores. You can take hyper threading into account. So for example if you have a quadcore cpu with HT enabled then it can handle 8 `Thread`s simultaenously.

Another thing is that this is usually done in an other way. Suppose you have 10 objects (plants, herbivores, whatever). Each has a method like `calculateNextState()`. You only have to calculate all states in a loop for your 10 objects then when you have a new state for all of them you refresh the GUI. You do this ad infinitum. You don't need a timer for that you only have to take into account the time it took for the calculation.

**An example:**

You have a herbivore which travels at the speed of 10 units (on the x axis). Its position is `(2,4)` The time passed between the previous calculation and `now()` is *200ms* You update its position to `(4,4)`. And so on...

As for the parallelization: you can create a `ThreadPool` and push `Runnable`s into it. Each `Runnable` is in fact the function for calculating the next state of a `GameObject` (I just gave a name for the creatures you have). When all `ThreadPool`s have finished their work you can update the GUI.

The main thing is: **you can't really update an arbitrary number of objects on your gui if you set a fixed time for the calculation because it may take longer than the time you set**.

Example: If you say "I want 1 updates every seconds" but you have 5.000.000 objects it may take 2 seconds for the calculation. That's why I suggest you should use the model I described. All state calculations should be parallelizable so you can distribute the work between threads.

There is a caveat however: you must take into consideration the case when 2 different plants/herbivores try to expand into the same cell which was empty after the previous calculation.

Comment: I want to make the system asynchronous since updating units in a particular order (double looping through a 2d array of stuff) doesn't make sense at all. Every unit should move whenever it's time for it to move, not when the loops reach it. Also, updating the GUI happens at constant time intervals regardless of the state of updates. The idea is to make every unit behave independently. Updating is not the renderering loop's job. On the last point: I  deny access to a cell by adding a Lock to it and locking that when the cell is being modified.

Comment: @PEC : what happens when two herbivores want to move into the same square at the same time? What happens where the rendering thread reads information about a newly created offspring before it fully initializes (position specified, but color `null` - or vice versa)? Sounds to me like you're treating multi-threading as a drop-in efficiency boost without considering all the resulting side effects. Adam Arold's suggestion to use work units is completely valid, and it gives you the same flexibility as "threads running everywhere", but with more control.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - handled it with a Lock object in each cell

Comment: @PEC: I'm curious as to how you specifically "handled it with a Lock object", but it's actually not pertinent to the point. The point is, however you implemented it, you've just departed from your original goal of getting it as "real as it gets" by imparting implementation details on your simulation. Shouldn't your simulation determine the implementation, and not the other way around?

Comment: I added a Lock lock variable in the Cell object and gave the Cell a lock() method which calls lock.lock(). Same with unlock. I kinda found a solution to my original problem btw, working on it now.

Comment: @PEC : you just described the **API**, not the **implementation**. That's a red flag, since it appears you consider just giving the ability to lock and unlock from the outside solves the problem of synchronization - it doesn't. **Please** see my answer before you disregard all the others and proceed with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well write my own answer.

First of all: **you will not be able to accurately represent your simulation world using a pure thread-per-entity, timer-based approach**.

Here's why:

[image: world model vs CPU model]

The left-hand side is, of course, the world model and the right-hand side, a simplistic threading model of the implementation, based on your approach.

Now, the important bits to point out are that:

- in your **simulation** model:

  1. the states of each entity are *fully internalized*. A herbivore, a plant, etc. contains all the information it needs to operate in itself.
  2. All entities are *autonomous*. An entity doesn't care whether something else is moving, being eaten, etc., or *how many* other entities are doing at the same time.
  3. All entities operate in *real time*. How they appear according to their internal state is how they appear in the world.
- in the actual **implementation** model:

  1. there is a *global state* in the main memory. All entities need to synchronize the thread local state with the global state, otherwise you'll run into inconsistencies.
  2. - Entity threads *compete for limited CPU resources*. A thread can be put into an inactive state at any time - and not even "your" thread to boot! *How many* other threads are executing becomes very relevant.
     - Entity threads *compete for main memory access*. When one thread locks a common lock, the other has to wait until it's unlocked.
  3. Entity threads operate completely decoupled from how they appear (i.e. in the GUI viewer).

From just those three points, I hope it's plain to see that the models are incompatible.

You might *try* to fit your world model into the threading model, but then you'll run into the problem of changing your world to suit the implementations. The locks you mentioned for example - they change how your world works, depending on your approach.

Of course, if, in this **specific case** you're **fine with this, go ahead** (and that means that you're also fine with the speed *decrease* that usually comes with a huge number of threads, and all the nice problems which come with synchronization).

However, in the **general case, you should choose your implementation according to your specification, not the other way around.**

If you heed the above, you have a lot of options, most of which rely on discrete simulation steps as described by [Adam Arold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336517/724361) and refined by [clwhisk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337359/724361). These models include:

- a limited number of worker threads processing work units using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ForkJoinPool`,
- encoding the grid model as a set of equations,
- etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define what *persistent threads* mean to you.

[Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29), like [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) are not [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) on current machines and operating systems (read about [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing)). For instance, they are not [serializable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) in the Java [sense](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) of the word.

You'll need to implement your own implementation of persistence of your computation (not of your threads). Designing your program in a [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) could be helpful. Have your own notion of persistent computation (e.g. by having each thread running a small loop, whose state is persistent and serializable).

Don't think of having many thousands (or even hundreds) threads; they are expensive resources. Consider having a small [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) (of at most a few dozen threads). The size of the thread pool should be configurable and should not depend upon the size of the data (or of the problem you are computing).

You may want to think in terms of [futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises), e.g. [Java futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) (sharing threads in a small-sized thread pool).

Comment: I want the thread to be able to listen to a timer and do stuff when the timer fires. Also, the thread should run as long as the unit that operates with it is alive.

Comment: I'm happy you want this. But not all wishes are reasonable. Having thousand of threads is probably not reasonable, unless you have a million-dollar machine (and then having tens of thousands of threads won't be effective).

Comment: The important thing is the concept. I could have Counter Strike as my game and 2 AI enemies. I want a different thread for every agent. That's 2 threads. Make these agents reeeeeally smart. Perfect job for 2 cores. Numbers are not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam's answer suggests, this is usually done with timesteps. Each creature has a countdown to its next action, and in simplest form the countdown would be an integer that decrements, with `calculateNextState()` called on everything each step. However you have much more flexibility than that. For instance, store the creatures in a priority queue sorted by (double) countdown. You can break ties randomly by shuffling their order in the queue, or add a random element to the countdown. The bottom line is, you have full control over the simulation using normal methods. Threads aren't the tool for the job - they sound like they do extra work and should be used every time there are parallel tasks but that's not true.